# How to grab the computer name with NodeJs / Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to retrieve the computer name from my computer so I can use it in comparison in my mysql query.

I would like to define `computerName` as a variable that grabs the user-defined computer name using `NodeJs`. This application is being run via electron for windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the standard nodeJS `os` API to retrieve the (host)name of a computer, [see this API documentation](https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/os.html#os.hostname) for more details.

```
const computerName = os.hostname()
```

Comment: For anyone coming here, I just discovered that `hostname` does not always equal `computerName`. It's causing me some headaches right now as we have a fleet of Macs which do not match.

Answer (score 4):

```
const cp = require('child_process')
const os = require('os')

function getComputerName() {
  switch (process.platform) {
    case "win32":
      return process.env.COMPUTERNAME;
    case "darwin":
      return cp.execSync("scutil --get ComputerName").toString().trim();
    case "linux":
      const prettyname = cp.execSync("hostnamectl --pretty").toString().trim();
      return prettyname === "" ? os.hostname() : prettyname;
    default:
      return os.hostname();
  }
}

console.log("getComputerName", getComputerName());
```

Inspiration Ref: https://github.com/egoist/computer-name

Comment: Excellent answer as sometimes networks will return a different name than is expected.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac the only way to reliably get the "ComputerName" as OP requested is to use a child process, which isn't ideal...

`cp.execSync('scutil --get ComputerName')`

Most of the time hostname will === ComputerName, but I found out the hard way today that this is not always the case.